# How to get assigned date of a Work Item in TFS using c#

Tags: c#

I am stuck at a point while writing a customized application using C# and TFS programming, I want assigned date of a WorkItem i.e when the X work item is assigned ti Y user.

Please help me out with this.I have tried below query

```
 private void getWorkItems(TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection, string user)
        {
            WorkItemStore workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)projectCollection.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
            string query = string.Format("select * from WorkItems WHERE [Work Item Type] <> 'Code Review Request' AND [Work Item Type] <> 'Code Review Response' AND( [Assigned To]='{0}'  OR [Changed By]='{1}' AND [Changed Date]>='{1}' AND [Changed Date]<='{2}') ",
                                                                                                            user,
                                                                                                            user);
            var workitems = workItemStore.Query(query).Cast<WorkItem>().Select(wi => wi);
            workItemGrid.DataSource = getWorkItemDetails(workitems, workItemStore, user).OrderBy(w => w.WorkItemNumber).ToList();
            workItemGrid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
            progressBarworkItems.Visible = false;

        }
```

Comment: You'll need to post some code showing what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to adapt the following code:

```
public static WorkItem GetWorkItem(int workItemId)
{           
    Uri tfsUri = new Uri("http://mytfsserver:8080/tfs");
    TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri);
    WorkItemStore workItemStore = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
    return workItemStore.GetWorkItem(workItemId);
}

public static void PrintRevisions(int workItemId)
{
    WorkItem wi = GetWorkItem(workItemId);

    foreach (Revision revision in wi.Revisions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Revision {0}", revision.Fields["Rev"].Value);
        string assignedTo = revision.Fields["Assigned To"].Value.ToString();
        string changedDate = revision.Fields["Changed Date"].Value.ToString();
        string changedBy = revision.Fields["Changed By"].Value.ToString();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(assignedTo))
            Console.WriteLine("Assigned To: {0} Date: {1} By: {2}", assignedTo, changedDate, changedBy);
    }
}
```